# How to use `std::vector.back()` correctly?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a bug in my code which I don't quite understand. According to the documentation, `std::vector.back()` returns a reference to the last element in the container, so here's what I did: ([live here](https://ideone.com/KFLSD0))

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(int id) : id(id) {
        std::cout << "foo " << id << " constructed" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "foo " << id << " destructed" << std::endl;
    }

    int id;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        foos.emplace_back(i);  // construct foo in place
        
        auto& foo = foos.back();
        std::cout << "Play with " << foo.id << std::endl;
    }
    
    for (auto&& foo : foos) {
        std::cout << "I'm foo " << foo.id << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

which yields the following output:

```
foo 0 constructed
Play with 0
foo 1 constructed
foo 0 destructed
Play with 1
I'm foo 0
I'm foo 1
foo 0 destructed
foo 1 destructed
```

So, right after the second instance of `Foo` is constructed, the first one gets destructed, why? because `auto& foo` goes out of scope? But when I print the `foos` vector, it still has two foos, what a surprise! At first glance it seems like `foos.back()` is making a copy, which is not true. What I really don't understand is, how is it possible that the constructor is called twice but the destructor is called 3 times, shouldn't they always come in pair?

Comment: You neglect what the vector does internally.

Comment: Because the vector reallocates memory, try `foos.reserve(2)`.

Comment: If you add copy (and maybe move) constructor to your class so that it prints something you'll see that the number of constructors and destructors is the same but the `vector` internally calls copy and move constructors (depending on the properties of your class) while reallocating its internal buffer.

Comment: Specifically, when the vector is reallocated, it reserves a new contiguous region of memory then copies its previous contents over to it. (It would rather move them, but `Foo` doesn't have a `noexcept` move constructor so it copies.)

Comment: Follow the rule of 5 and also implement the copy and move constructor and assignment operator with messages. You'll see what's happening.

Comment: FYI, in C++17 onward, `emplace_back()` returns a reference to the new element: `auto& foo = foos.emplace_back(i);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for mentioning that shorthand, I didn't know it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening here is that when you `.emplace_back(1)` the `std::vector` does not have enough space for two elements, so it has to reallocate, copy/move all the existing elements to the new allocation, then `emplace_back` the new one. Hence you see the only existing element being destroyed from the old allocation.

This goes away if you `.reserve(2)` before the loop: https://godbolt.org/z/oj8fWhznP

```
foo 0 constructed
Play with 0
foo 1 constructed
Play with 1
I'm foo 0
I'm foo 1
foo 0 destructed
foo 1 destructed
```

You can also use `.capacity()` to check the size of the allocation, which indeed confirms the theory: https://godbolt.org/z/a88xfqa7f

```
--- 0 ---
capacity: 0
foo 0 constructed
capacity: 1
Play with 0
--- 1 ---
capacity: 1
foo 1 constructed
foo 0 destructed
capacity: 2
Play with 1
```

Adding logging definitions for move/copy constructors and assignment operators might give you better insight into what `std::vector` is doing internally.

Comment: Thanks! In my real code, my real `Foo` class does have a move ctor and move assignment operator, the problem is that it's inheriting from a base class which doesn't, so all the data members in the base class got messed up...